# How do I create a VM from an existing FreeBSD 8.2 PreRelease server?

Tags: freebsd, virtualbox, virtual-machine

I need to create a VM (VirtualBox) out of an existing `freebsd 8.2 pre-release i386` machine.

I need to replicate the exact same environment and I can't rebuild from scratch because FreeBsd 8.2 PreRelease has been discontinued.

I have never done this, and I haven't found a good lead yet.

What is the classic workflow?

Comment: You can still get the 8.4 install ISO: http://ftp.freebsd.org/pub/FreeBSD/releases/i386/ISO-IMAGES/8.4/

Comment: yeah, unfortunately I do need to stick to `freebsd 8.2 pre-release` that is to support legacy build. a long story ...

Comment: You can check out any commit to the FreeBSD repository, so if you can find which commit corresponds to the 8.2-PRERELEASE you're running, you can grab it and build your own installation media from the source, or build from source on your VM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with netcat (ssh works too; but I'm assuming both the old machine and the new machine are on the same "secure" LAN).

Briefly:

- Build your VM with your disk space and whatnot.
- Boot to the FreeBSD install DVD (probably doesn't matter which version).
- Use the post installation options to partition and format your drives (they don't necessarily have to be the same size as long as they are big enough for your data). Don't forget swap.
- Add boot blocks (I haven't done this for EFI yet, but your VM should probably still support MBR which I've done successfully several times)
- start a "Fixit shell"
- mount your new file system[s] somewhere

  ```
  Fixit# mkdir /mnt/root
  Fixit# mount /dev/da0s1a /mnt/root
  ```
- get a network address (`ifconfig`, or `dhclient` as you prefer -- you used to have to create `/var/db` before `dhclient` would work; but I don't think that's necessary anymore?)
- start a netcat listener on your new machine:

  ```
  Fixit# cd /mnt/root
  Fixit# nc -l 80 | tar -xvf -
  ```
- over on the old machine, `cd` to root and start pumping a `tar` out to the new machine.

  ```
  # cd /
  # tar -cvf - . | nc 10.20.0.102 80
  ```
- repeat for each of your file systems
- you might have to edit `/etc/fstab` on the new machine if, for example, your old hardware had IDE drives and your new ones are SCSI.

You can optionally:

- add compression to the `tar` commands (`-z` or `-j` as you prefer)
- use `dd` instead of `tar`. I've never tried it, but it ought to work. If you use `dd` you probably don't have to partition or format your new disks; but they will have to be the same size or bigger.

Comment: I'm remembering an exotic problem. tar uses /tmp and ESXi used a RAM disk for /tmp and it wasn't big enough. You had to unmount /tmp and put it on a disk. I don't know if you will run into that with virtualbox.

Comment: Your answer is rather exiting. I was looking at the clonezilla option but was confronted to replicating in its entirety a machine i.e. with all the user home folders (~500GB of data) that I am not interested in. Your solution may allow me to replicate only what I need. Cheers.

Comment: `tar` has an option `--one` that will tell it not to descend through mount points, in case you want to copy one filesystem at a time.